# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed while taking the value of Resultset

Tags: java, sql-server

```
public static ResultSet getTestDatafromSQL(String QueryString) throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    try {
        String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\sqlexpress;DatabaseName=master;integratedSecurity=true;";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
        if (conn != null) {
            DatabaseMetaData dm = (DatabaseMetaData) conn.getMetaData();
            System.out.println("Driver name: " + dm.getDriverName());
            System.out.println("Driver version: " + dm.getDriverVersion());
            System.out.println("Product name: " + dm.getDatabaseProductName());
            System.out.println("Product version: " + dm.getDatabaseProductVersion().toString());
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            // Create and execute a SELECT SQL statement.
            resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(QueryString);
            System.out.println(resultSet);
            while(resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1));
                //return resultSet.getString(1);
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (conn != null && !conn.isClosed()) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return resultSet;
}
```

Now In other class, I am calling that...

```
@Test(enabled = true)
public void query() throws XPathExpressionException, IOException, SQLException {
    ResultSet sql = utilities.getTestDatafromSQL("SELECT ACCOUNT_NO1,CREDIT_LMT from [BCMASTER$] Where CAST(Trim(BCM_CREDIT_LMT) as float) >5000");
    //System.out.println(sql.first());
    System.out.println("SQLValue:"+sql.getString(1));
    System.out.println("SQLValue:"+sql.getString(2));
}
```

I am getting FAIL Sat Aug 15 10:25:24 IST 2020 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed. - Test Case Failed

To read the result set, db connection should be open?

From each query I will get different columns, so is there any possible can we store it in array and return is only possibility or resultset can get the value?

Comment: *FYI:* `DriverManager.getConnection()` cannot return null, so the `if (conn != null)` statement is unnecessary / superfluous / redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You close the `Connection` in method `getTestDatafromSQL()` so no point in returning a `ResultSet`. Consider storing the `ResultSet` in a `java.util.List` and have method `getTestDatafromSQL()` return a `List` rather than a `ResultSet`.

Alternatively, don't close the `Connection` in method `getTestDatafromSQL()` and return the `ResultSet` and the method that calls `getTestDatafromSQL()` (which is method `query()` according to the code in your question) can close the `Connection`. In interface `ResultSet` call `getStatement()` which returns a `Statement` and in interface `Statement` call `getConnection()` which returns the `Connection` and then you can close it.

Another alternative would be to use a [`CachedRowSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/cachedrowset.html)

Here is my implementation of the first option described above.

```java
public static List<List<String>> getTestDatafromSQL(String QueryString) throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> row;
    try {
        String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\sqlexpress;DatabaseName=master;integratedSecurity=true;";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
        if (conn != null) {
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            // Create and execute a SELECT SQL statement.
            resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(QueryString);
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                row = new ArrayList<>();
                row.add(resultSet.getString(1));
                row.add(resultSet.getString(1));
                result.add(row);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if (conn != null && !conn.isClosed()) {
                conn.close();
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

Here is my implementation of the second option.

```java
public static ResultSet getTestDatafromSQL(String QueryString) throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\sqlexpress;DatabaseName=master;integratedSecurity=true;";
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    // Create and execute a SELECT SQL statement.
    resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(QueryString);
    return resultSet;
}
```

Then you would call the method and then close the `Connection` like this:

```java
ResultSet sql = utilities.getTestDatafromSQL("SELECT ACCOUNT_NO1,CREDIT_LMT from [BCMASTER$] Where CAST(Trim(BCM_CREDIT_LMT) as float) >5000");
// Handle the ResultSet
sql.getStatement().getConnection.close();
```